# Why can we apply the strong maximum principle?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

I am considering the following section of Peter Grindrods „Pattern and Waves“.

> We begin by considering a scalar equation $$ u_t=\Delta
> u+f(u,x,t),\quad x\in\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n, t>0. $$ Here $f$ is
>   smooth (say, continously differentiable).
>
> Suppose $\overline{u}\colon\Omega\times [0,T]\to B$, some bounded
>   subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $$
> \overline{u}_t\geq\Delta\overline{u}+f(\overline{u},x,t); $$ then we
>   say that $\overline{u}$ is a super-solution. If
>   $\underline{u}\colon\Omega\times [0,T]\to B$, and $$
> \underline{u}_t\leq\Delta\underline{u}+f(\underline{u},x,t), $$ then
>   we say that $\underline{u}$ is a sub-solution.
>
> Now suppose that there exist constants $\alpha,\beta
> (\alpha^2+\beta^2\neq 0)$ such that $$
>  \alpha\overline{u}-\beta\nabla\overline{u}.n\geq
>  \alpha\underline{u}-\beta\nabla\underline{u}.n,\quad
>  x\in\partial\Omega, t>0, $$ (n is the outer normal to
>    $\partial\Omega$); and that $$
>  \overline{u}(x,0)\geq\underline{u}(x,0), x\in\Omega. $$ Then we claim
>   that $$ \overline{u}(x,t)\geq \underline{u}(x,t),\quad x\in\Omega. $$

---

The author also gives a short "proof".

> To see this, set $$ w=\overline{u}-\underline{u}. $$ Then the mean
>   value theorem implies $$ w_t-\Delta w\geq f_u(\underline{u}+\theta
> (\overline{u}-\underline{u}))w $$ for some mapping
>   $\theta\colon\Omega\times [0,T]\to [0,1]$. The result follows from the
>   strong maximum principle for linear parabolic equations [15] (The
>   point is that $w$ is initially nonnegative and the boundary conditions
>   ensure  that if it becomes negative it must do so at an interior point
>   of $\Omega$. We then can construct a contradiction.)

---

*Unfortunately, I have no opportunity to have a look at the mentioned maximum principle cited from book [15] (which is a book by P.C. Fife).*

So we set $w=\overline{u}-\underline{u}$ and note that
$$
w_t-\Delta w\geq f(\overline{u},x,t)-f(\underline{u},x,t)=f_u(\underline{u}+\theta(\overline{u}-\underline{u})w,x,t)w
$$
where the last identity comes from applying the mean value theorem.

Up to here, I can follow the proof.

Now, i write this inequality by using a parabolic linear operator in order to bring it in the usual textbook form for maximum principles:

$$
Lw = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial^2 x_i}-f_u(\underline{u}+\theta(\overline{u}-\underline{u},x,t)w-(-w_t)\geq 0.
$$
Now, if 
$$
f_u(\underline{u}+\theta(\overline{u}-\underline{u},x,t)\leq 0,
$$
I could use the strong maximum principle for the function $-w$, i.e. making some statement about non-negative maxima of the function $-w$ (resp. about negative minima of the function $w$).

However, I can neither find the assumption
$$
f_u(\underline{u}+\theta(\overline{u}-\underline{u},x,t)\leq 0
$$
nor deduce it from the text.

---

But let's suppose for a moment that
$$
f_u(\underline{u}+\theta(\overline{u}-\underline{u},x,t)\leq 0.
$$

The proof by contradiction which the author mentions maybe works like this:

Assume we have at least one point $(x_0,t_0), t_0>0$ such that
$$
\overline{u}(x,t)<\underline{u}(x,t).
$$
Then $-w(x_0,t_0)>0$.

By initial- and boundary conditions, the point $(x_0,t_0)$ had to be an inner point of $\Omega\times [0,T]$ since $w<0$ can only happen at inner points.

From this, can we deduce that in the interior of $\Omega\times [0,T]$ we have a negative minimum $M$ (say at some point $(x',t')$ which equals $(x_0,t_0)$ in case this is the only point such that $\overline{u}<\underline{u}$) of $w$ and that  - by the strong maximum principle - 
$$
w(x,t)=M
$$
for all $(x,t)$ which are on the horizontal line on which $(x',t')$ lies?
 (in particular for boundary points on this line, which gives a contradiction since there $w$ cannot be negative)?

Thats how I did understand the proof.

Comment: Is $f_u\geq 0$?

Comment: @Jeff I do not know. At least the text does not say that.

Comment: Is the PDE $u_t = \Delta u + f(u,x,t)$? (there are some typos in your post). Generally the maximum principle only holds when $f_u \leq 0$ (sorry I wrote wrong way in previous comment). Are there any other assumptions on $f$ in your book (there must be something)?

Comment: @Jeff Sorry for the typos. Yes, the Pde is $u_t=\Delta u+f(u,x,t)$.  - Considering $w_t-\Delta w\geq f_u(...)w$, why does the maximal principle only hold for $f_u\leq 0$? I am a bit confused since the maximum principles are always formulated in the form $Lu\leq g$ or $Lu\geq g$ and I am not sure what are $L$ and $g$ here and whether we need $\leq$ or $\geq 0$. - - I will have a closer look at the book. (Unfortunately, I only have the first 100 pages.)

Comment: For a linear equation $w_t-\Delta w + cw = 0$, maximum principle requires $c\geq 0$. Here $c=-f_u$. A good reference for the maximum principle for parabolic equations is Evans PDE book Chapter 6.

Comment: Okay, I guess then here we have $L[w]=w_t-\Delta w-f_u(\underline{u}+\theta(\overline{u}-\underline{u}))w\geq 0$. But I cannot find any assumption on $f_u$. It is only said that $f$ is smooth (say, continuously differentiable).

Comment: Moreover, I think that the usual way to write this in textbook form would rather be $L[w]=\Delta w+f_u(\underline{u}+\theta (\overline{u}-\underline{u}))w-w_t\leq 0$, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73969/discussion-between-jeff-and-salamo).

Comment: @Jeff I edited my post. Maybe it is more clear now? Do you think my argument is correct and is what the author had in mind?

Comment: That's not exactly right. I just remembered the trick that works here; I'll write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick you can use to adjust the sign of the zeroth order term so that the maximum principle applies. You have a solution $w$ of

$$w_t - Lw \geq cw$$

in a parabolic cylinder, with $w\geq 0$ on sides and base, and you want to show $w\geq 0$ in the interior. Define $v = e^{-\lambda t}w$. Then $v$ satisfies

$$v_t + (\lambda-c)v - Lv \geq 0.$$

Provided $c$ is bounded, you can choose $\lambda$ large enough so that $\lambda -c\geq 0$. Now you can apply the standard strong (or weak) maximum principle to conclude that $v \geq 0$ everywhere, and so $w\geq 0$.

Comment: Am I right that your operator L is $Lw=\Delta w$ and your c is $c=f_u(...)$? And the parabolic cylinder is $\Omega\times [0,T]$?

Comment: How can we conclude that $v\geq 0$ everywhere?

Comment: Yes. You use the minimum principle. $v$ attains its minimum on the sides and base, where $v\geq 0$ (since $w\geq 0$ on sides and base). There are similar versions of the maximum principle for your boundary conditions. The whole point is the trick to change variables and introduce a zeroth order term $(\lambda-c)v$ with the right sign.

Comment: Sorry I did not see yet why Minimum principle. You mean if we assume that w is negative, then w (and v) has a negative minimum M in the interior and hence v also has value M on the sides and the base which is a contradiction since there v is nonnegative?

Comment: But for minimum principle I need $...\leq 0$ and not $\geq 0$, right?

Comment: Moreover, if you say everywhere, do you mean on the horizontal lines on which the interior point with the negative minimum lies?

Comment: No, you need $\geq 0$ for minimum principle. Choose $\lambda$ large enough so that $\lambda-c\geq 1$. Then at a minimum you have $v_t\leq 0$ and $\Delta v \geq 0$, hence $(\lambda-c)v \geq 0$ and so $v\geq 0$ at its minimum.

Comment: What I mean is: Can't we instead consider $\Delta w+cw-w_t\leq 0$ resp. for $v=e^{-\lambda t}w$, $\Delta v+(c-\lambda)v-v_t\leq 0$ and choose $\lambda >0$ such that $(c-\lambda)\leq 0$? Then the Minimum principle makes a Statement about the case when $v$ takes its (negative!) Minimum in the interior, or?

Comment: This is exactly the same thing, you are just multiplying both sides by $-1$.

Comment: Usually we write parabolic equations as $u_t-Lu +cu =f$, and not with minus signs on both sides. For elliptic equations it is natural to see both $Lu=f$ and $-Lu = f$ (but not so for parabolic).

Comment: Yes, but in this form ist more familiar to me since I read in a textbook this distinction between $L\leq 0$ (Statement about negative minima) and $L\geq 0$ (Statement about non-negative maxima). And I guess here we Need a Statement about negative minima. Am I right with the following Argument: Suppose $w<0$ for at least some Point $(x_0,t_0)$ with $t_0>0$. Then $v(x_0,t_0)<0$. By the boundary conditions this has to happen in the interior. Among the Points in the interior where $v<0$ some point attends the negative minima and this implies by the Minimum principle: v<0 at some boundary Points..

Comment: Namely on that boundary Points that can be connected to the point with the minima (in a Special way which I do not mention here but can be found in the textbooks). Contradiction since $v\geq 0$. - Is this the right way? Sorry for repeating myself but I Need some confirmation. :-)

Comment: Yes, that's basically right.

Comment: By the way, what does the boundary condition, which should be $\alpha w-\beta\nabla w.n\geq 0$ tells us exactly? I interprete it as $w(x,t)$ minus the rate of Change in the normal outer direction is non-negative. But why does this mean that $w$ stays non-negative on the boundary forever? Maybe because this implies that $\Delta w.(-n)\geq 0$ and this means we either stay at the same boundary point or move into the interior...

Comment: I assume $n$ is the inward normal? Then if $w$ has a minimum on $\partial \Omega$ we have $\nabla w \cdot n \geq 0$ and so $w \geq 0$ (provided $\alpha,\beta>0$). So $w$ cannot have negative minimum on boundary.

Comment: The textbook from which this whole comparison principle is cited says that $n$ is the outer normal.

Comment: Normally you need some conditions on the signs of $\alpha,\beta$. If $n$ is outward normal, then $\alpha>0$ and $\beta < 0$ is necessary...